# $L^p$ compactness for a sequence of functions from compactness of cut-off

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory

Fix $p \in [1,\infty)$. Let $f_n:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$, $n \in \mathbb N$, be a sequence of  $C^1$ functions. For every fixed $m\in \mathbb N^*$, suppose that the sequence of functions $$\{f_{n}\psi_m(f_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$$ has a strongly convergent subsequence in $L^p([a,b])$. Here  $\psi_m$ is a smooth cut-off function such that
$$\psi_m(f) = 
\begin{cases}
1 \qquad \text{ if } |f|\ge 1/m \\
0 \qquad \text{ if } |f|\le 1/(2m)
\end{cases}
$$
and $0 \le \psi_m \le 1$.

Suppose in addition that $\Vert f_n \Vert_{L^p} \le C$ (for a constant $C>0$ that does not depend on $n,m$ and for all $p \in [1,\infty]$) and suppose that every subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\psi_m(f_{n_k})\}_{n_k}$ is also compact in $L^p$ for any fixed $m$.

**How can we prove that $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ also has a strongly convergent subsequence in $L^p([a,b])$?**

Under these assumptions, can we prove the result following [this argument](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox/4993#4993), which is rewritten below?

> For any $f$,
>
> $$ f - f \psi_m (f) = \begin{cases} f & \text{if } |f| \le 1/2m,\\ 0 &
> \text{ if } |f| \ge 1/m.\end{cases}$$
>
> In particular,
>
> \begin{align*}  \int |f - f \psi_m (f)|^p &= \int_{|f| <1/m} |f - f
> \psi_m (f)|^p \\ &\le \int_{|f|\le 1/2m} |f|^p + \int_{1/2m \le
>  |f|<1/m} |f - f \psi_m (f)|^p \\ &\le \frac{b-a}{(2m)^p} +
>  \frac{(b-a)}{m^p}\\ \Rightarrow \|f - f \psi_m (f)\|_{L^p} &< C/m
>  \end{align*}
>
> where $C$ depends on $b-a, p$ only. Note we used $|1-\psi_m|\le 1$.
>
> Then using a diagonal argument, there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$
> of $\{f_n\}$ and $f\in L^p [a, b]$ so that for each $m$, the sequence
> $\{ f_{n_k} \psi_m (f_{n_k})\}$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$. Now we show
> that $\{f_{n_k}\}$ also converges to $f$ in $L^p$: for any
> $\epsilon>0$, fix one $m\in \mathbb N$ with $C/m < \epsilon/2$. Since
> $\{ f_{n_k} \psi_m (f_{n_k})\}$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$, there is
> $K$ so that $\| f_{n_k} \psi_m (f_{n_k}) - f\| _{L^p} < \epsilon/2$
> for all $k\ge K$. Then
>
> \begin{align*} \|f_{n_k} -f\|_{L^p} \le \|f_{n_k} - f_{n_k} \psi_m
>  (f_{n_k}) \|_{L^p} + \| f_{n_k} \psi_m (f_{n_k}) -f\|_{L^p} <
> \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2  \end{align*}
>
> for all $k\ge K$.

---

If the above fails, you can also add the assumption $\Vert D_x(f_n\psi_m(f_n))\Vert_{L^1} \le C_m$, where $C_m$ is a constant that depends only on $m$.

---

This question is motivated by two previous questions on Math Stack Exchange [[A]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775973/lp-compactness-for-product-of-two-sequences-of-functions/3776126?noredirect=1#comment7774430_3776126)

Comment: "how can we prove": we can't because it is not true. In your hypotheses , (f_n)  can be unbounded in any L^p for p>1.

Comment: @PietroMajer Thanks, I've edited the question.

Comment: I think one shouldn't rely on content remaining indefinitely in the formatting sandbox.  (Remember MO and other SE sites are meant for long-term archiving.)  Probably better to move it here.

Comment: @LSpice I put the link just to give credit to the original writer of this proof, but I rewrote it in the body of the question to preserve it in case of changes to the Sandbox link

Comment: [Sounds good](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368125/lp-compactness-for-a-sequence-of-functions-from-compactness-of-cut-off#comment928738_368125) to me.  (I didn't realise you weren't the author.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$g^m_n := f_n \psi_m(f_n).$$ The assumptions mean that $(f_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence in $L^p(a,b)$ and that $(g_n^m)_n$ is relatively compact in $L^p(a,b)$ for each $m$. We use the [Frechet-Kolmogorov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_theorem) characterizing compactness in $L^p$ spaces to show that this transfers to $(f_n)_n$. (Then not only $(f_n)_n$ has a convergent subsequence, but also every subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$.)

Split and estimate
\begin{align*}\|\tau_h f_n - f_n\|_{L^p(a,b-h)} &\leq \|\tau_h(f_n-g_n^m)\|_{L^p(a,b-h)} + \|\tau_h g_n^m - g_n^m\|_{L^p(a,b-h)} \\ & \qquad + \|g_n^m - f_n\|_{L^p(a,b-h)} \\ & \leq \|\tau_h g_n^m - g_n^m\|_{L^p(a,b-h)} + 2\|g_n^m - f_n\|_{L^p(a,b)}.\end{align*}

(I use $(\tau_h g)(x) := g(x+h)$ because it is more familar to me.)

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Choose an $m$ large enough such that $\|g_n^m - f_n\|_{L^p(a,b)} < \varepsilon/3$ for all $n$ (calculation in OP). Now, for the chosen $m$, choose $h_0$ small enough such that $\|\tau_h g_n^m - g_n^m\|_{L^p(a,b-h)} < \varepsilon/3$ for all $h \leq h_0$, uniformly for all $n$; this is possible by the Frechet-Kolmogorov theorem. ($(g_n^m)_n$ is clearly bounded in $L^p(a,b)$ if $(f_n)_n$ is.)

Then $\|\tau_h f_n - f_n\|_{L^p(a,b-h)} < \varepsilon$ for all $h \leq h_0$ uniformly in $n$ and again the Frechet-Kolmogorov theorem says that $(f_n)_n$ is relatively compact in $L^p(a,b)$.

---

Due to interest by the OP, here also a less abstract diagonal argument. Iteratively for $m=1,2, \dots$, choose nested subsequences $(f_{n_m(i)})_i$ such that $(f_{n_m(i)}\psi_m(f_{n_m(i)}))_i$ converges (to some $f^m$). Set $h_j := f_{n_j(j)}$. Then split $$h_k - h_\ell = (h_k - h_k\psi_m(h_k)) + (h_k\psi_m(h_k) - h_\ell\psi_m(h_\ell)) + (h_\ell\psi_m(h_\ell) - h_\ell).$$

For $\varepsilon > 0$ given, the norms of the first and last summands can be made smaller than $\varepsilon/3$ uniformly in $k,\ell$ by choosing $m$ large enough (calculation in OP). For $k,\ell \geq m$, $(h_k)$ and $(h_\ell)$ are subsequences of $(f_{n_m(i)})_i$, so $(h_j \psi_m(h_j))_j$ converges and is a Cauchy sequence. Thus, choosing $k,\ell$ large enough makes the middle summand smaller than $\varepsilon/3$. Hence $(h_j)_j$ is also a Cauchy sequence and, by completeness of $L^p(a,b)$, convergent.

---

This should not be a contradiction to the counterexample posted on MSE in the link in OP, since there the assumption was only that $(g_n^m)_n$ admits a convergent subsequence for each $m$, and it was shown that then $(f_n)_n$ need not admit a convergent subsequence. Here OP asked for $(g_n^m)_n$ relatively compact for each $m$ which the counterexample sequence is not, if I see it correctly.

Comment: @Zac I added a diagonal argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for your addition!

Comment: I have just one more curiosity: would all of this still work if we defined $$\psi_m(f) = 
\begin{cases}
1 \qquad \text{ if } |f - 1|\ge 1/m \\
0 \qquad \text{ if } |f - 1|\le 1/(2m)
\end{cases}
$$ instead of as in the original question?

Comment: Uh, you roughly would need to make sure that the $(f_n)$ stay away from $1$ in a uniform manner, I guess. (In the sense that the measure of the set where $|f_n - 1| \leq 1/m$ goes to zero uniformly in $n$ as $m \to \infty$.)

Comment: It seems fair. Why wasn't this needed in the previous case?

Comment: With the modified $\psi_m$, the constant one function is a nonzero fixed point of $f \mapsto f-\psi_m(f)$ for every $m$. For the original $\psi_m$, there is no nonzero fixed point for each $m$. Essentially, this makes the calculation in the OP possible.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. What kind of assumption of $f_n$ would imply this condition on the measure of the set $\{|f_n -1| \le 1/m\}$? For example, a bound on the derivative? higher integrability?

Comment: I've put this in a separate post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368583/lp-compactness-for-a-sequence-of-functions-from-compactness-of-product-with-c

Comment: You should consider upvoting and accepting Hannes 'answer, Zac.