# $L^p$ compactness for a sequence of functions from compactness of product with cut-off

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory

Fix $p \in [1,\infty)$. Let $f_n:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$, $n \in \mathbb N$, be a sequence of  $C^1$ functions. For every fixed $m\in \mathbb N^*$, suppose that the sequence of functions $$\{f_{n}\psi_m(f_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$$ has a strongly convergent subsequence in $L^p([a,b])$ and  that every subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\psi_m(f_{n_k})\}_{n_k}$ is also compact in $L^p$ for any fixed $m$. Here  $\psi_m$ is a smooth cut-off function such that $0 \le \psi_m \le 1$ and
$$\psi_m(f) = 
\begin{cases}
1 \qquad \text{ if } |f - 1|\ge 1/m \\
0 \qquad \text{ if } |f -1 |\le 1/(2m)
\end{cases}
$$

Assume also that $\Vert f_n \Vert_{L^p} \le C$ (for a constant $C>0$ that does not depend on $n,m$  for all $p \in [1,\infty]$). . If necessary, also asssume that $\Vert D_x(f_n\psi_m(f_n))\Vert_{L^1} \le C_m$, where $C_m$ is a constant that depends only on $m$.

- **How can we prove (or disprove) that $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ also has a strongly convergent subsequence in $L^p([a,b])$?**
- If the result is not true, what additional assumption would make it so?

---

This question is motivated by my previous question [$L^p$ compactness for a sequence of functions from compactness of cut-off](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368125/lp-compactness-for-a-sequence-of-functions-from-compactness-of-cut-off).

---

Comment: I guess the definition of the functions $\psi_m(f)$ should be something like 
$$\psi_m(f)(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 \qquad \text{ if } |f(x) - 1|\ge 1/m \\
0 \qquad \text{ if } |f(x) -1 |\le 1/(2m)
\end{cases}
$$
for each $x\in [a,b]$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yes, exactly. I was just trying to use a shorter notation.

Comment: The condition “every subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\psi_m(f_{n_k})\}_{n_k}$ is also compact in $L^p$” is very strong. 
It can be shown that it is equivalent to $\{f_{n}\psi_m(f_{n})\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ has finitely many values. I guess you mean that 
a set $\{f_{n}\psi_m(f_{n})\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is totally bounded instead.

Comment: @AlexRavsky You're probably right

Comment: Then a usual condition providing the existence of a strongly convergent subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ is a total boundedness of $\{f_n\}$. It can be easily assured by the following natural assumption: there exists a subsequence $\{c_k\}$ of positive numbers converging to zero and an increasing subsequence $\{m_k\}$ of natural numbers such that $\|f_n- f_{n}\psi_{m_k}(f_{n})\|_{L^p}<c_k$ for each $n$ and $k$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thank you. What other (more explicit) assumption on $f_n$ would make this requirement hold?

Comment: For each $n,m$ put $X_{n,m}=\{x\in [a,b]: |f_n(x)-1|<1/m\}$. Let $\mu$ be the standard Lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$
I guess 
$$\|f_n- f_{n}\psi_{m}(f_{n})\|^p_{L^p}=\int_{X_n,m} |f_n(x)|^p|1-\psi_m(f_n)(x)|^p d\mu\le (1+1/m)^p\mu(X_{n,m}).$$
Thus the required condition should be $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sup_{n}\mu(X_{n,m})=0.$

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks! Is there anything that we can assume on $f_n$ (smoothness, integrability, a condition on the derivatives?) that would make this condition on $\mu(X_{n,m})$ automatically true?

Comment: @AlexRavsky This property on $\mu(X_{n,m})$ has essentially to do with level sets, so maybe continuity helps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111715/discussion-between-alex-ravsky-and-zac).

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear, as stated, but the following can be proved. Let $B$ be a bounded set of $L^p(0,1)$ and assume that for every $\epsilon>0$ the set $$B_\epsilon=\{f \chi_{\{|f| \ge \epsilon\}}, \ f \in B\}$$ is relatively compact in $L^p$, then $B$ is relatively compact, too. In fact, given $\epsilon >0$, a finite  $\epsilon/2$-net for $B_\epsilon$ is a $\epsilon$-net for $B$, since $(0,1)$ has finite measure. Changing characteristic functions with smooth cut-off (around 1, as in the original problem), should not change the conclusion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How can one prove the claim in your last sentence?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about the argument with nets (because I'm not very familiar with them). How can one make it more explicit?

Comment: Sorry for the language which was a bit too cryptic. For $B$ I want to prove it is totally bounded, that is for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite number of balls $B(f_i, \epsilon)$ covering it. Do it first for $B_\epsilon$ (with $\epsilon/2$ balls), by assumption, and then note that the double balls cover $B$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How does compactness follow from the covering?

Comment: This is a standard and powerful equivalence which holds in metric spaces.

Comment: Ok, now I see. I'm still just a bit confused about the last claim: Consider $B_m = \{f\psi_m(f): f \in B \}$ as in the body of the question. If $B_m$ is totally bounded, how can I prove that $B$ is also totally bounded?

Comment: You should try to  follow the argument I gave above.

Comment: It seems not to be working because, in the notation above, $f\chi_{\{|f-1|\ge \epsilon\}}$ is not arbitrarily small (it's actually arbitrarily close to $1$). But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111709/discussion-between-giorgio-metafune-and-zac).